# Splitting a start and end date by interval in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

Is there any function to split a start and end date into chuncks of `$interval` days (or months)? For example:

```
$interval = new DateInterval('P10D');
$start    = new DateTime('2012-01-10');
$end      = new DateTime('2012-02-16');

$chunks = splitOnInterval($start, $end, $interval);

// Now chunks should contain
//$chunks[0] = '2012-01-10'
//$chunks[1] = '2012-01-20'
//$chunks[2] = '2012-01-30'
//$chunks[3] = '2012-02-09'
//$chunks[3] = '2012-02-16'
```

I think [`DatePeriod`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) can help, but i didn't find any way on how i can use it.

Comment: *(tip)* http://derickrethans.nl/talks/time-zendcon10.pdf

Comment: @Gordon thank you, sorry i dind't realized that was a duplicate. Voted for closing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check this article on [how to iterate over valid calender days](http://shiplu.mokadd.im/18/interate-through-each-valid-calendar-days/).

In php its something like,

```
$start = strtotime('2012-01-10');
$end1 = strtotime('2012-02-16');
$interval   = 10*24*60*60; // 10 days equivalent seconds.
$chunks = array();
for($time=$start; $time<=$end1; $time+=$interval){
    $chunks[] = date('Y-m-d', $time);
}
```

Comment: if I have to devide 18 months (2017-01-01, 2018-30-06) into equal let say 5 number of months, then what changes I will need to make in the above code?.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example to iterate over days, over month is working accordingly with other interval

```
<?php

$begin = new DateTime( '2012-11-01' );
$end = new DateTime( '2012-11-11' );
$end = $end->modify( '+1 day' );

$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
}
?>
```